# What is the difference between different rated RCCBs except for the price?

Tags: circuit-breaker

Say there's a need to install a 25A30ma Residual Current Circuit Breaker (i.e. ABB FH202 AC-25/0,03). It is going to be followed by a normal circuit breaker, to protect the wiring and the RCCB (16A). Specified RCCB is not in stock, however, there are 32A30ma and 40A30ma variations available of the same brand (latter being a bit cheaper).

Can I take and install higher-rated circuit breaker (40A30ma) instead of required 25A30ma? And if so - what is the guiding principle of when to use smaller-rated RCCBs except for the price?

*Note: the question is about RCCBs, not the RCBOs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: An RCD should be able to **handle more current** then the nominal Amperes of the RCB. The more the better since losses are lower and the chance to destroy/damage the RCD via an overload is lower.

Some versions are most probably more expensive (even having lower Ampere ratings) because of much lower production numbers. In many countries a RCD protects more then 1 circuit, so a 40A or 63A version is standard.

---

When a second (or more) parallel circuit are added alongside the first 16A circuit (if the upstream installation is rated accordingly), the RCD would protect both circuits. Of course, **neutral and ground/Protection Earth must never be connected downstream of a RCD**. An overload in both circuits at the same time is very unlikely.

A 25A30ma Residual Current Device can handle 25A in normal operation.
This Ampere value should be **always greater** then the breaker's Ampere value.

Here is the reason:
A Residual Circuit Breaker RCB of 16A is **NOT** specified to interrupt immediately when more then 16A is flowing, e.g. 18A. 
But it interrupts after certain seconds/minutes taken into account that short time higher currents must be tolerated. F.e. a 16A RCB could interrupt a 20A current only after 40 seconds. But of course it must interrupt every shortage with high currents as soon as possible (hundreds or thousands of Ampere in the milisecond range).

Note: if there was a shortage in a circuit, the RCD should be exchanged since it could have been damaged by the high short current.

Comment: Never connect neutral and PE or neutral and ground DOWNSTREAM of a RCD - it would make the RCD useless. It may be appropriate to connect neutral and PE UPSTREAM of an RCD, e.g. in a TN-C-S system.

Comment: For the sake and theme of the original question, RCD is the same as RCCB, right?

Comment: I get also confused and have to look it up. It seems that there are different abbr. in different countries, which were also changing during the last years.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "A residual-current device (RCD), or residual-current circuit breaker (RCCB), is a device that quickly breaks an electrical circuit to prevent serious harm from an ongoing electric shock."

Comment: And RCB is a common name for a simple Overload Circuit Breaker, right? Or should it be a CB (Circuit Breaker). Sorry about all those terminology clarifications - there's just so many names for things in different countries

Comment: Yes, I think RCB is the standard name (until the next change by the European Commission or other institutions).